# Conditional input in dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is it possible to make Input conditional in dash? Below is my code. What I want to accomplish is, I want the tabs to be the input only if the main_tab == 'A', and if the main_tab=='B', I want the tab to be state (not input)

```
@app.callback(
    Output('store-data', 'data'),
    Input("inputid", "n_submit"),
    Input("search-button","n_clicks"),
    Input("tabs-main","value"),
    Input("tabs","value"),
    State("inputid", "value"),
    prevent_initial_callback=True,
)
def store_data(n_submit,n_clicks,main_tab,tab,id_value):
    if n_submit or n_clicks>0:
        if main_tab=='A':
            uniqueid = b64.encode(id_value)
            locations_staging = query_staging.get_location(uniqueid,tab)
            data = query_staging.get_data(locations_staging)
            return data
        elif main_tab=="B":
            uniqueid = b64.encode(id_value)
            locations_cu = query_cu.get_location(uniqueid)
            data = query_cu.get_data(locations_cu)
            return data
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a condition inside a callback. But the problem might be when you want to read the values of State and Input to make a condition because they are classes on module `dash.dependencies`. Therefore, you cannot make a condition like:

```
 State('input-1-state', 'value') if Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks') > 1
                                 else State('input-2-state', 'value')
```

You can use help(Input) to read more about Input and State.

I think you can follow your current way to make conditioning.